# Implementations of Mobile IP on linux

Tags: linux, kernel

Are there any standard implementations of Mobile IP for Linux?

If I want to support mobile IP for a network, what all needs to be done?

If I have to write code from scratch, is it **likely** that a kernel module will suffice or I would have to make changes to the kernel code.

I just need a bit of headstart to know where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

It appears likely to me that it can be done without requiring any kernel code at all, you can achieve it by having a userspace daemon create a tun interface (much like a VPN client would typically do) and then route or encapsulate packets in whatever way is required for mobile IP. The userspace daemon may have to modify the kernel's routing table but that's ok.

Examples of the tun interface users are openvpn and Qemu.